# Architecture of regression with Convolution Neural Network

Tags: networking, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, conv-neural-network

I would like to use AlexNet architecture to solve a regression problem, which is initially used to classification tasks. 
Furthermore, for learning step I want to include a parameter to batch size.

So I have several question :

- What do I need to change in the network architecture to achieve a regression ? Precisely in the last layer, the loss function or other things.
- If I use a batch size of 5, what is the output size in the last layer ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to share:

- **Q Framework:** Which deep learning framework you are working with and/or share specific piece of code that you need help modifying

  **A:** eg. TensorFlow, PyTorch, Keras etc.
- **Q Type of Loss, Output size:** What is the task you are trying to achieve with regression? This would impact the kind of loss you want to use, the output dimension, fine-tuning the VGGnet etc.

  **A:** eg. Auto-colorization of grayscale images (here is an [example](http://richzhang.github.io/colorization/)) is an example of a regression task, where you would try to regress the RGB channel pixel values from a monochrome image. You may have an L2 loss (or some other loss for improved performance). The output size should be independent of the batch size, it would be determined by the dimension of the output from the final layer (i.e. the `prediction op`). The batch size is a training parameter that you can change without having to alter the model architecture or output dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

- I'm working on TensorFlow 1.3

- I would like to make age estimation using regression, so in output I expect only an age. As I have a small dataset, I fine-tune the network. 
My working basis is [https://github.com/kratzert/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow].

Comment: In that case, the last fully connected / dense layer can replaced by a layer with an output dimension of 1, and the loss could be an L2 loss between the predicted output and the actual age.

However, pretrained AlexNet trained on Imagenet is useful for vision tasks where one can benefit by fine-tuning or transfer learning. I would recommend re-evaluating the need of using a Imagenet pretrained network for regression task for ages.

FYI - that link seems to be broken

Comment: Sorry, the good link https://github.com/kratzert/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow. Ok ! So if I understand well, the layer fc8 (you can open the file called "alexnet.py") could be replaced by "self.fc8 = fc(dropout7, 4096, num_out=1, relu=True, name='fc8')"  ? Do you think it's better to use VGG ?

Comment: I should have been clearer when I talked about the benefits of using a pretrained CNN architecture. The benefit of using a pretrained network and finetuning is because that helps with reducing training time and potentially improving performance for vision tasks. This is because the expectation is that the multiple layers in the CNN architecture have learnt hierarchical representations like edge detectors and gabor filters in early layers, more complicated structures in later layers and so on.

Comment: Utilising these weights gives a big advantage for vision tasks like localization or detection or segmentation etc. However, in your task of regressing ages, I am not sure if there is even an advantage in using pretrained weights and fine-tuning.
It would be a good experiment and an interesting result if it turns out that it benefits, although I doubt that.

Comment: As far as using the github repo as your base is concerned, you are right, you would have to change the `num_out` to `1`. Also, you want to change the [loss op](https://github.com/kratzert/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow/blob/master/finetune.py#L96) and the way you import your data, because you do not have (labels)[https://github.com/kratzert/finetune_alexnet_with_tensorflow/blob/master/finetune.py#L82] per say, rather you have a target positive real number / integer that you want to regress.

Comment: Trying out different architectures with hyperparameter tuning is usually, and unfortunately the best way to find out which approach best suits your task.

PS - sorry for multiple comments, it is due to character limit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your answer, this is an amazing contribution for me !
Yes you are right about the way to load data. I already change it to import directly labels and not references.